# Angular: Getting error while using ng-option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, ng-options

I have this schema:

```
teams: [
   {
      id: 1,
      name: "Spain"
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      name: "Germany"
   }
]
```

now I have this select element:

```
<select ng-model="betSchema.winnerId" ng-options="team.name for team in teams track by team.id">
    <option value="-1">Tie</option>
</select>
```

the `betSchema` object looks like this (as default):

```
{
   winnerId: -1
}
```

Here is the result I see:

[image]

The problems are:
1. I can't see the tie option, and there is one mysteries "blank" option (the first at the top).
2. when the `betSchema` looks like this:

```
{
   winnerId: 2
}
```

I am expecting to see Germany option to be selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mn4SH/4/

There are a couple of things.

1. When using ng-options Angular is going to overwrite your option tags so you have to add it to your model like such:

   `scope.teams = [{ 
             id: -1,
             name: "Tie"
              },
              {
                 id: 1,
                 name: "Spain"
              },
              {
                 id: 2,
                 name: "Germany",
              }];`
2. Second, you can use track by but using "as" would also work in this context: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select. You can use obj.dataToBeStoredInModel as obj.labelOfData for obj in objList to get the id for ng-options.

Comment: I have pushed the "tie team" to the teams array like this: `$scope.teams.unshift( {id: -1,name: "Tie"});` and changed the select to this: `<select ng-model="bettype.betSchema.winnerId" ng-options="team.id as team.name for team in teams"></select>`. Still I am getting a blank option and it is impossible to select any option rather then the blank one.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of it? Sounds like there is a Javascript error if nothing is loading.

Comment: No there is no fiddle, but I can point out the the `betSchema.winnerId` is loaded from server (via service), so when I hard coded setting it - it works fine. but when it is loaded it messes it all up. any ideas? Thanks for the help\!

Comment: Sure thing. If using Google Chrome, check the Network tab to see where the request that is loading the betSchema.winnerId. Click on the request and see what the results are. That sounds like the network request is returning something that Angular doesn't like (i.e. undefined).

Comment: Yes there was a problem with the data within the DB. Thank you very much! will accept your answer gladly :)

Comment: Only one more problem the change not taking affect in the $scope, any idea? I have updated your fiddle but it seems to work there... here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/Mn4SH/5/